# How can keep the user logged in even after the browser has closed with Identity ASP.NET MVC framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-identity-2

Currently, each time the user browser closes, he/she will have to login again.

When they login, this is the code that I use to sign them in Identity.

```
SignInManager.SignIn(user, false, false);
```

Here is how my Authentication is configured today

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {        
        AuthenticationType = "SomeCustomName",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        },
        SlidingExpiration = false,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
    });

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
}
```

How can I keep the use logged in for 60 minutes even if he/she closed the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make 2 changes.

```
AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
SlidingExpiration = true,
```

You want to use a cookie so that it is persisted in the browser and can be re-read if the web site is opened again later. You also want to slide the expiration so that way each request will extend the lifetime of the cookie, otherwise the user will have to re-authenticate after 60 minutes from the *first* time the cookie is issued.

Supporting documentation:

- [CookieAuthenticationOptions Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [DefaultAuthenticationTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.defaultauthenticationtypes_fields(v=vs.108).aspx)

Finally the call to sign in should pass `true` for the 2nd parameter. The 3rd parameter is only relevant if you are using 2 factor authentication.

```
SignInManager.SignIn(user, true, false);
```

*Side note*

For security it is not a bad idea to also set option `CookieHttpOnly = true` which ensures that the cookie cannot be accessed by scripts/client side code.

Comment: Why are you recommending to set `AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie`? I thought just just changes the name of the cookie. In my case, I want to rename the cookie that is used. Also, are you saying to change SlidingExpiration from `false` to `true`?

Comment: @Jaylen - That is not what that property is for. If you want to change the name of the cookie there is a property called `CookieName`. See the 1st link I posted in my answer [CookieAuthenticationOptions Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions(v=vs.113).aspx) it is listed on that page.

Comment: @Jaylen - one more change: My code was meant to set `SlidingExpiration` to `true` but I had accidentally left it as `false`.

Comment: Ok great. What about how I log the username `SignInManager.SignIn(user, false, false);` doesn't that have to change?

Comment: @Jaylen - correct, the 2nd parameters should be `true`. The 3rd parameter is relevant only for 2 factor authentication.

Comment: @Jaylen - if this answers your question please consider marking it as an answer. If you feel it was helpful please consider upvoting it.

Comment: I will mark it the correct answer once I test it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to set sessions' cookie expire time after successful login:

```
Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
```